# How to parse JSON with dynamic key value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON array with dynamic key value (room number, it will change every time I run the code). I'm wondering how to access inner JSON array with this key value. Here's what I have tried and it throws an error.

JSON Array(data)

```
[{"6011":
 [{"occupancy":"2","time":"2017-11-10 00:00:00"},
 {"occupancy":"1","time":"2017-11-10 00:30:00"},
 {"occupancy":"2","time":"2017-11-10 01:00:00"}]
}]
```

Code to access

```
var room = outerJSON.name;

var jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));

var innerArray = jsonObject[room]; // returns undefined
var innerArray2 = jsonObject.get(room); // Uncaught TypeError: jsonObject.get is not a function
```

Comment: It seems like your Json object is inside an array what does `jsonObject[0][room]` do?

Comment: What is `outerJSON.name`?

Comment: Is `room` `6011`? Since your object is wrapped in an array, you need to `find` that object first: `jsonObject.find(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(room))`.

Comment: Why are you calling `jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data))`? What's the point in stringifying it, then parsing it again?

Comment: @Cerbrus That question is about finding objects with a fixed property name. This one is about finding objects by a dynamic key name.

Comment: @Xufox: No, this question is just about getting the first entry from an array. The OP just doesn't realize that.

Answer (score 2):

Your object are inside an array, so you should point your code to the first column of the array `jsonObject` using `[0]` like :

```
var innerArray = jsonObject[0][room];
```

```js
var data = [{
  "6011": [{
      "occupancy": "2",
      "time": "2017-11-10 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "occupancy": "1",
      "time": "2017-11-10 00:30:00"
    },
    {
      "occupancy": "2",
      "time": "2017-11-10 01:00:00"
    }
  ]
}];

var room = "6011";
var jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
var innerArray = jsonObject[0][room];

console.log(innerArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to parse the json? Or why are you even stringifying it here?

Comment: Since the author already using jQuery, why not ?

Comment: The problem is in accessing the data. I'd suggest keeping the answer as short as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the answer already has one line ? (The snippet just uses the same code in the OP + [0])

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `room` has the value `6011` or `"6011"`, and assuming `{"6011":`…`}` is not always the only object in the array, you need to `find` that object first, since your object is wrapped in an array. You can then access the room property by `[room]`.

```js
var jsonObject = [{ "6011": [{ "occupancy": "2", "time": "2017-11-10 00:00:00" }, { "occupancy": "1", "time": "2017-11-10 00:30:00" }, { "occupancy": "2", "time": "2017-11-10 01:00:00" } ] }, { "6012": [{ "occupancy": "2", "time": "2017-11-10 00:00:00" }, { "occupancy": "1", "time": "2017-11-10 00:30:00" }, { "occupancy": "2", "time": "2017-11-10 01:00:00" } ] }],
  room = 6011;

var foundObject = jsonObject.find(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(room));

console.log(foundObject && foundObject[room]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```